Sequelize issue in a docker container
I'm trying to start two containers with docker-compose, but only one works, which is the database container. My API container in nodejs didn't start and when I ran the command docker logs <container_id> --details this error appeared:
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/app/npx sequelize init'
     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1248:15)
     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:27)
     at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
     at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:217:24)
     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:166:5)
     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:30:49 {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: []
 }

This is the only dockerfile I wrote myself and built with docker build -t <my_dockerhub_user/image_name:tag>:
FROM node:alpine3.20

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/app

EXPOSE 3333

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]

docker-compose.yml:
version: "2.2"

services:

  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    build: .
    restart: "always"
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "true"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: controle_de_estoque

  application:
    restart: "always"
    image: lucasnascdevv0042/smtimage:nodeapp
    command:
      - npx sequelize init
      - npm run db:migrate
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    environment:
      - DB=controle_de_estoque
      - DATABASE_HOST=<my_vm_ip>
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=

The package.json
{
  "name": "controle-estoque-restaurante",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon src/server.js",
    "swagger-autogen": "node src/swagger.js",
    "build": "sucrase ./src -d ./dist --transforms imports",
    "db:migrate": "npx sequelize db:migrate",
    "db:init":"npx sequelize init"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.2",
    "sucrase": "^3.35.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^8.1.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "express-delay": "^0.2.0",
    "helmet": "^7.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.9.7",
    "sequelize": "^6.37.3",
    "swagger-autogen": "^2.23.7",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^5.0.1",
    "cors":"2.8.5"
  }
}


.sequelizerc:
const { resolve } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  config: resolve(__filename, 'src', 'config', 'database.js'),
  'models-path': resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'models'),
  'migrations-path': resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'migrations'),
  'seeders-path': resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'seeds'),
};

I've already tried using the sequelize commands in the dockerfile and in docker-compose but in neither case it worked and other several solutions but I didn't get the expected result, I would appreciate it if someone could help.

Your Compose command: syntax is wrong.  It looks like you're trying to use this to run multiple commands in addition to the image's CMD, but a container only runs one command and that listing is a listing of words (hence the specific syntax error you get).  For migrations in particular, consider this answer to set up an entrypoint wrapper script that runs on its own.
